# Mudar a posição de um objeto em um mapa

Tags: javascript, html5, array, canvas

Galera, preciso de uma lógica que, detectando se o valor de `x, y` mudou, troque a posição de um objeto no mapa.

Tenho um mapa que contém `50x50 tiles`, e nesses tiles existem objetos que eu posso mover utilizando o código abaixo:

```
var playerx = 10;
var playery = 15;

function drawMap() {
    for (i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            var drawTile = map[i][j];
            var drawObj = objectMap[i][j];
            var xpos = (i-j) * tileH + mapX;
            var ypos = (i+j) * tileH/2 + mapY;

            ctx.drawImage(tileImg[drawTile], xpos, ypos);

            if (drawObj) {
                ctx.drawImage(objectImg[drawObj-1], xpos, ypos - (objectImg[drawObj-1].height));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Para adicionar o objeto eu uso essa propriedade:

```
objectmap[playerx][playery] = 1;
```

E para remover eu uso a função `delete`:

```
delete objectmap[playerx][playery];
```

O que acontece é que o objeto fica nas posições 10 e 15 que são os valores das variáveis `playerx` e `playery`,  mas eu tenho uma função que pega a posição do mouse e ao clicar muda a o valor de `playerx` e `playery`, acontece que conforme o valor da função muda, vai adicionando objetos no mapa, sem remover o último.

Desse modo o mapa fica com vários objetos, mas eu quero que o objeto fique apenas onde os valores das variáveis apontam.

Vocês sabem como fazer isso com um `if` ou de outro modo?

Comment: Podes rever a pergunta e clarificar melhor a pergunta? dá para juntar um jsFiddle para ficar mais claro?

Comment: e porque estou no tablet, e como coloco as tagues code no stackoverflow?

Comment: Editei a pergunta pra você, você pode colocar códigos utilizando o símbolo `

Comment: ninguem sabe como fazer nao?

Comment: Atenção moderadores podem apagar o meu post e tópico pois já resolvi esse problema.